# Fedora Linux Network won't stay connected to network

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, fedora, fedora-23

I'm testing a fresh installed fedora 23 workstation on a Lenovo B5080 in my office. The network works fine at first (ping request works) but after sometimes the ping request starts to error Destination Host Unreachable.

```
ping 8.8.8.8
...
68 bytes from 8.8.8.8: ecmp_seq=2744 ttl=47 time=127 ms
...
From 192.168.1.150 icmp=6221 Destination Host Unreachable
...
```

(which 192.168.1.150 is the workstation IP)

I have to turn off & on my wireless card every time to make it work. Later it was using DHCP and on every restart I had to kill dhclient every time to make it work.

I've made an static IP address for the station but it still get disconnected every now and then (no need to kill dhclient anymore).

I've checked routes, iptable and everything seems alright but or arp response I have this:

`gateway (192.168.1.1) at <incomplete> on wlp9s0`

(I checked arp before getting disconnected and it had the right MAC Address.)

I have no clue why is this happening but I guess my workstation is somehow corrupting its arp table... Any idea what is going on?

P.S. (I tested this on other networks and it has the same problem)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the ARP table. It's just a cache, and its entries expire after some time. When your Wi-Fi link breaks (e.g. due to driver problems), you stop receiving ARP packets (nor any other packets I assume) and the cache entry expires.

Comment: @grawity do you suggest any way to troubleshoot and find out how the link breaks?